# String class value variable used in equals() method: how and when is it defined?

Tags: java, string

I have investigated **equals()** method in String class and found that it uses **value** - an array of chars. Here this variable is:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

    ...
}
```

As a string is created then this **value** is immediately defined and seen in a debug mode. However I do not find a place where this **value** is defined.

My question. When we are creating a string like this:

```
String str = "My string";
```

how and when this **value** is defined?

**Edit**: I have seen 3 constructors that @xenteros mentioned. However **this.value** is defined as an array of chars only in the last constructor. Directly I am not invoking it. Also if you set breakpoints in these constructors it will not stop there.

Answer (score 2):

`value` is initialized in each constructor.

```
public String() {
    this.value = new char[0];
}

public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}

public String(char value[]) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length);
}
```

[source code for String.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

When you execute

```
String str = "My string";
```

there is no magic happening. `JVM` creates new `String` calling a constructor. It's explained in the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1)

**Edit**:

In the JVM available in OpenJDK the following file contains the native code in which String literals are created. It's done in C++, so no Java constructors are called.

[Link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#l164)

Comment: What exact constructoir is called in this case?

Comment: @KirillCh it's JVM dependent. It's not part of the specification so it might be different in each JVM. I guess it is the one which takes `char[]` as a parameter so there is no infinite recursion.

Comment: this.value is defined as an array of chars only in the last constructor. However directly I am not invoking it. Also if you set a breakpoint in this place it will not stop there. So my question is open.

Comment: So it means that your answer is not about this question?

Comment: @KirillCh it is about the first part: `However I do not found a place where this value is defined.`

Comment: @KirillCh `original.value` is also a `char[]`

Comment: Right now after this answer I (and you) also do not find this place. :)

Comment: String is a part of the language. Is it required that the compiler 'call' any constructor at run time in the case of a compile time constant?  I don't see why. The literal ```"My string"``` is interned, which can be done at compile time, so the initialization is simply putting that reference into ```str```, and no runtime construction is required.